# django haystack - how to use with current view having some context

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have a view that puts some context and renders the template from this context.  I want view display all the things if no search query is there, and show searhed things, if anything searched.

```
class MyCurrentView(View):
     def get(self, request):
         data = { 'users': User.objects.all() }
         return render_to_response("mytemp.html", ..

urls.py:
      url(r'^search/$', MyCurrentView.as_view())
```

Now, I am integrating this with SEarchView like this:

```
class MyCurrentView(SearchView):  (If u observe, I subclassed SEarchView).
     template = 'mytemp.html'
     def get(self, request):
         data = { 'users': User.objects.all() }
         return render_to_response...

     def get_context_data(self, ...):
          print "....this should print"  #But not printing. So, unable to add data
     return data

urls.py:
      url(r'^search/$', MyCurrentView.as_view())  
      # as_view() gave me error, so I did MyCurrentView() , may be thats y, get_context_data not calling.
```

Will provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Got the answer for this, just override extra_context definition. But, can anyone tell me the difference between calling VIEwname.as_view() and ViewName() in urls.py ?

Comment: Haystack's SearchViews aren't like Django's regular class-based views. They don't use the `as_view` pattern.

Comment: Haystack now has traditional django CBV's via PR #1130.  See my comment below or https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/pull/1130

Answer (score 0):

New Django-style class based views were added via PR #1130 to django-haystack:

- https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/pull/1130

You can now use search views like you normally would with django (see changes in pull request).

```
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView

class MySearchView(SearchView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # do whatever you want to context
```